# Add two y-axis scales to the same graph

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I would like to configure the y-axis so the values are more interpretable. [image: I would like to configure the y-axis so the values are more interpretable. Preferably I would have 'mean_Kincaid' on the left y-axis and 'mean_Score' on the right y-axis.]

This is the code I tried:

```
ax = Statements.plot(x='Date', y='mean_Kincaid', legend=True, 
title="Fed Statement Kincaid and Sentiment scores over time")
Statements.plot(x='Date', y='mean_Score', ax=ax)
Statements.plot(secondary_y='mean_Kincaid', style='g', ax=ax)
```

[image: Resulting in:]

When running:

```
ts = Statements.set_index('Date')
ts.mean_Kincaid.plot()
ts.mean_Score.plot(secondary_y=True)
```

I get:

[image]

Which is much different from my original graph. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-on-a-secondary-y-axis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`secondary_y`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-on-a-secondary-y-axis) keyword argument.

```
ts = Statements.set_index('Date')
ts.mean_Kincaid.plot()
ts.mean_Score.plot(secondary_y=True)
```

If you'd like to display a legend and axis labels, use something like

```
ts = Statements.set_index('Date')
ax = ts.mean_Kincaid.plot(legend=True)
ts.mean_Score.plot(legend=True, secondary_y=True)
ax.set_ylabel('mean_Kincaid')
ax.right_ax.set_ylabel('mean_Score')
```

Comment: Thank you, but this distorts my data it seems. I've updated my question, do you have any idea of what is going on? thanks again

Comment: I guess it is graphing the lines in a different scale. How do I label the scales to their proper variable? Also, if you know how to change the colors (to perhaps a dotted blue line rather than an orange one) and add a legend that would be great! thanks!

Comment: @Graham I've added an example which shows how to label the axes and add a legend. I'm not sure what you mean by "distorts my data." Your plot looks good to me, the two series are just on different scales, which is the whole point of a secondary axis.

Comment: Please read through the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-on-a-secondary-y-axis) for examples of alternate line styles.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for throwing in the style questions!